# Use variables from a file that had imported the variables already using @use SASS

Tags: sass

How would I use variables from a file that had imported the variables already using @use SASS file(`abstract.scss`).

eg:

```
// Folder Structure

/abstracts/_mixins.scss
/abstracts/_variables.scss
/abstracts/_something.scss

/abstracts/abstracts.scss
```

```
// _variables.scss

$color-primary:blue
```

```
// abstracts.scss

@use './mixins';
@use './variables';
```

```
// home.scss

@use '/somefolder/abstracts/abstracts.scss' as a

h1{
 color:a.$color-primary;
}
```

I get an error "SassError: Undefined variable..." pointing to the line in home.scss. Yes I know I can import the variables directly to the home.scss, but I would like to know if it is possible to import through another file "abstracts.scss". Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With new rule `@use` you indeed need to `@use` the files you need indeed to every scss file where you need it. In `home.scss` you need the variable from `_variables.scss` but did not `@use` the file direct.

Using the file `abstracts.scss` which `@use` the variables file itself is not enough. `@use` in `abstract.scss` effects, that you can use the vars in `abstract.scss` itself but not in the files which `@use` the `abstract.scss`.

**There are two possibilities to solve that:**

```
// Possibility A
// ###> in file: home.scss
// use variables.scss direct

@use 'somefolder/abstracts/variables;


// Possibility B
// ###> in file: abstracts.scss
// forward variables.scss so it can be used from other file which uses abstracts.scss

@forward 'variables`;
```

Here are more information about the new rule `@forward` which is introduced as supplement to `@use` so you can organize your projects/modules: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward